# Can a break statement be used in situations other than loops?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop, break

I am currently studying the while-loop statement area in Python. That specific question came into my mind. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Read the docs - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break

Comment: What do you want to break out of other than loops?

Comment: @luk2302 Hi, and thanks for your reply. As a beginner in python, I try to have a deep interest in it. Whenever a question occurs in my mind, I search for as many answers as possible. My curiosity led me to that specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break):

> **break** may only occur syntactically nested in a **for** or **while** loop, but not nested in a function or class definition within that loop.

> When **break** passes control out of a **try** statement with a **finally** clause, that **finally** clause is executed before really leaving the loop.